# Loading texture in segments

Tags: ios, opengl-es, libpng

I'm working on an Open GL app that uses 1 particularly large texture 2250x1000. Unfortunately, Open GL ES 2.0 doesn't support textures larger than 2048x2048. When I try to draw my texture, it appears black. I need a way to load and draw the texture in 2 segments (left, right). I've seen a few questions that touch on libpng, but I really just need a straight forward solution for drawing large textures in opengl es.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the texture size support depends on device, I believe iPad 3 supports 4096x4096 but don't mind that. There is no way to push all those data as they are to most devices onto 1 texture. First you should ask yourself if you really need such a large texture, will it really make a difference if you resample it down to 2048x_. If the answer is NO you will need to break it at some point. You could cut it by half in width and append of the cut parts to the bottom of the texture resulting in 1125x2000 texture or simply create 2 or more textures and push to them certain parts of the texture image. In any of the cases you might have trouble with texture coordinates but this all heavily depends on what you are trying to do, what is on that texture (a single image or parts of a sophisticated model; color mapping or some data you can not interpolate; do you create it at load time or it is modified as it goes...). Maybe some more info could help us solve your situation more specifically.